# QML disappearing objects

Tags: qt, qml

I have issue with disappearing item. If there is just "loginBox" - it looks fine (picture removed from hosting service), but when I'm adding "savedAccountsBox", "loginBox" disappears, there is just "savedAccountsBox" (picture removed).

Also the structure seems to be fine (picture removed).

What is wrong?

This is my code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow1
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }


    GridLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            //anchors.margins: 20
            //rowSpacing: 20
            //columnSpacing: 20
            //flow:  width > height ? GridLayout.LeftToRight : GridLayout.TopToBottom

            TabView {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Tab {
                    title: "Accounts"

                    GroupBox {
                        id: loginBox
                        x: parent.width * 0.05
                        y: parent.height * 0.05
                        width:  parent.width * 0.4
                        height: parent.height * 0.9
                        title: "Login"

                        TextArea {
                            id: textArea1
                            x: parent.width * 0.125
                            y: parent.height * 0.125
                            width:  parent.width * 0.15
                            height: parent.height * 0.07
                        }
                    }

                    GroupBox {
                        id: savedAccountsBox
                        x: parent.width * 0.6
                        y: parent.height * 0.05
                        width:  parent.width * 0.3
                        height: parent.height * 0.9
                        title: "Saved Accounts"

                        ListView {
                            id: listView1
                            x: parent.width * 0.1
                            y: 0
                            displayMarginBeginning: -50
                            //anchors.centerIn: parent
                            width:  parent.width * 0.5
                            height: parent.height * 0.7
                            spacing: 10
                            scale: 1.6
                            delegate: Item {
                                x: 5
                                width: 80
                                height: 40
                                Row {
                                    id: row1
                                    spacing: 10
                                    Rectangle {
                                        width: 40
                                        height: 40
                                        color: colorCode
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: name
                                        font.bold: true
                                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            model: ListModel {
                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Grey"
                                    colorCode: "grey"
                                }

                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Red"
                                    colorCode: "red"
                                }

                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Blue"
                                    colorCode: "blue"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }




                Tab {
                    title: "Blue"
                }
                Tab {
                    title: "Green"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use editor instead of designer. Something like "width:  parent.width * 0.4" is not good coding style in QML, so it can be much better to write correct code by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object is declared within another object's definition without declaring it as a value for a particular property, it is assigned to [default property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) value.
`Tab`'s default property is `sourceComponent`. In your case, you assign `loginBox` to default property, and then immediately overwrite it with `savedAccountsBox`. To fix it, you should wrap your two `GroupBox` into one `Item`.

```
Tab {
    title: "Accounts"
    Item {
       GroupBox {
           id: loginBox
       }
       GroupBox {
           id: savedAccountsBox
       }
    }
}
```

P.S. You should prefer anchoring and layouts rather than absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing the absolute positioning and dimensioning and using Layouts instead. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicklayouts-index.html

Here an example of your code working

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow1
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }


    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        TabView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Tab {
                title: "Accounts"

                RowLayout {

                    GroupBox {
                        id: loginBox
                        title: "Login"

                        TextArea {
                            id: textArea1
                        }
                    }

                    GroupBox {
                        id: savedAccountsBox
                        title: "Saved Accounts"
                        Layout.fillHeight: true

                        ListView {
                            id: listView1
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            spacing: 10
                            delegate: Item {
                                width: row1.width
                                height: row1.height
                                Row {
                                    id: row1
                                    spacing: 10
                                    Rectangle {
                                        width: 40
                                        height: 40
                                        color: colorCode
                                    }

                                    Text {
                                        text: name
                                        font.bold: true
                                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            model: ListModel {
                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Grey"
                                    colorCode: "grey"
                                }

                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Red"
                                    colorCode: "red"
                                }

                                ListElement {
                                    name: "Blue"
                                    colorCode: "blue"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }




            Tab {
                title: "Blue"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "Green"
            }
        }
    }
}
```